# Determining pending operations with NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I am displaying a UIView containing a button giving the user an option to undo something. The view stays visible for a few seconds, then closes. I am creating the view as follows:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(endUndoOption) withObject:self afterDelay:delay];
```

Then canceling it if necessary using the following:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(endUndoOption) object:self];
```

Is there any way to determine if there is an operation scheduled (in this case, endUndoOption)? Or if the timer has begun? Currently I am doing this with a BOOL flag but was wondering if there is a way to check to see if there has been one queued? THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check Cocoa Pods (http://cocoapods.org) BlocksKit pod, http://zwaldowski.github.io/BlocksKit/, there is a special category on NSObject with two very useful methods:

`+ (id)bk_performBlock:(void (^)(void))block afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;`

which returns an id which is cancellation handle.

And

`+ (void)bk_cancelBlock:(id)handle;`

to cancel your scheduled perform.

So, to achieve your target, you can store the cancellation handle in some property, e.g.

```
self.endUndoCancellationHandle = [[self class] bk_performBlock:^{ 
                                              [self endUndoOption];
                                              self.endUndoCancellationHandle = nil;
                                          } afterDelay:delay];
```

then cancellation:

```
if (self.endUndoCancellationHandle)
{
     [[self class] bk_cancelBlock:self.endUndoCancellationHandle];
     self.endUndoCancellationHandle = nil;
}
```

To check if something is scheduled, just check if you currently have the handle:

```
if (self.endUndoCancellationHandle)
{
...
}
```